# SQL server set AUTOGROW_ALL_FILES fails

Tags: sql-server

I try to execute this:

```
USE [MyDB]
GO
declare @autogrow bit
SELECT @autogrow=convert(bit, is_autogrow_all_files) FROM sys.filegroups WHERE name=N'PRIMARY'
if(@autogrow=0)
    ALTER DATABASE [MyDB] MODIFY FILEGROUP [PRIMARY] AUTOGROW_ALL_FILES
GO
```

And it fails with:

> Database state cannot be changed while other users are using the database 'HistoryDBTest'

How can I go around it?

Comment: I recently ran into this in setting up some new databases and can't for the life of me think of why the database couldn't be under use and have this setting changed!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll need to change the database to single user mode. Use this **with care**; considering the error is "other users are using the database" this means that those users will have their connections to the database cut off, and their transactions rolled back.

```
USE master;
GO
ALTER DATABASE MyDB SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
GO
USE [MyDB];
GO
DECLARE @autogrow bit;
SELECT @autogrow = CONVERT(bit, is_autogrow_all_files)
FROM sys.filegroups
WHERE name = N'PRIMARY';
IF (@autogrow = 0) ALTER DATABASE [MyDB] MODIFY FILEGROUP [PRIMARY] AUTOGROW_ALL_FILES;
GO
USE master;
GO
ALTER DATABASE MyDB SET MULTI_USER;
```

Comment: Actually sp_who2 shows that the only active connection is by ... me :-/ and it is probably the tab I have open in ssms... weird!

Comment: @cnom I assume that was a separate connection. If you have 2 windows open in SSMS, you have 2 connections, and thus 2 "logins" (kind of like if you were to log into the same website in 2 different browsers). 2 windows don't share the same connection; so if you try to do something where at most there can be 1 connection, you need to close all but 1.

Comment: but i am sure I remember only one tab open... ok i probably not remeber correctly and u r right @Larnu